# Investment in business where bribe is given to take work

Tags: investment

Asalam O Alikum

By grace of Allah i have a good business of my own. Many years ago one good friend of my who now lives in a different city wanted to start a construction business but he didn’t had enough money to do business. I had agreement with him that i will become sleeping partner in his business and invest money in his business.

He gives me profit return according to our agreed terms. He also does work of good quality of customers but recently i came to know from some people that he takes construction contracts by giving commission. But there is no confirmation of this since we both are in different cities and i never interfered in business since I’m already busy in my own work.
Currently I’m confused is the profit which im getting Halal or not? And also have no idea how to talk about this with him because this can also break our friendship.

Answer (score 0):

It's halal up until the point you discovered that he was taking bribes. Intention and knowledge matters in Islam. Once you discovered this, then it is haram, as you appear to already understand. It's then a duty to do something about this, and as you have also realised, this is not simple: it may break your friendship, it may make business difficult.

Ask yourself this, had you known about his activities in taking bribes would you have begun a friendship with him, and a business relationship?

How you deal with this will depend upon your own diplomatic skills. It also suggests a business opportunity - a business that deals with conflicts like this, as you cannot have been the first person to discover such a conflict of interest. You could call this business, business counselling...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. Since now i know what he is doing so its better for me to withdraw my investment from business since whatever is now earned after knowing all this will be considered haram.